# kinect 2 not working with ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a problem to use kinect2 in my ROS and look for lots of ways to configure that but still cannot.
Firstly, I follow the instructions from:

> **https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2**

This link is the kinect driver in linux. It seems that everything works fine except

> **sudo dpkg -i debs/{libva,i965}*deb; sudo apt-get install -f**

it tells me that it doesn't contain libva and i965 directory, and fails.

I used another way to install them:

> **sudo apt-get install libva-dev libjpeg-dev**

I skipped this step, and followed the instruction to the end:

> **./Protonect**

And this gives me four images which includes depth image and RGB image. However, I noticed that, when I executed this command, the output in the screen shows:

> jimmy@eaibot:~/libfreenect2/bin$
> ./Protonect
> Version: 0.2.0
>
> Environment variables:
> LOGFILE=<protonect.log>
>
> Usage: ./Protonect [-gpu=] [gl |
> cl | clkde | cuda | cudakde | cpu]
> []
>
> ```
>     [-noviewer] [-norgb | -no
> ```
>
> depth] [-help] [-version]
>
> ```
>     [-frames <number of frames to process>]
> ```
>
> To pause and unpause: pkill -USR1
> Protonect
>
> [Info] [Freenect2Impl] enumerating
> devices...
>
> [Info] [Freenect2Impl] 13 usb devices
> connected
>
> [Info] [Freenect2Impl] found valid
> Kinect v2 @4:9 with serial
> 002305464947
>
> [Info] [Freenec
>
> t2Impl] found 1 devices
>
> **libva info: VA-API version 0.35.0**
>
> **libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 1**
>
> **libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with operation
> failed,driver_name=i965**
>
> [Error] [VaapiRgbPacketProcessorImpl]
> vaInitialize(display, &major_ver,
> &minor_ver): operation failed
>
> [Info] [Freenec
>
> t2DeviceImpl] opening...
>
> [Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] transfer
> pool sizes rgb: 20*16384 ir:
> 60*8*33792
>
> [Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] opened
>
> [Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl]
> starting...
>
> [Debug] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] status
> 0x090000: 9729
>
> [Debug] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] status
> 0x090000: 9731
>
> [Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl]
> submitting rgb transfers...
>
> [Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl]
> submitting depth transfers...
>
> [Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] started
>
> device serial: 002305464947
>
> device fi
>
> rmware: 4.0.3911.0
>
> [Debug] [DepthPacketStreamParser] not
> all subsequences received 0
>
> [Debug] [DepthPacketStreamParser] not
> all subsequences received 1008
>
> [Debug] [DepthPacketStreamParser]
> skipping depth packet
>
> [Debug] [DepthPacketStreamParser]
> skipping depth packet
>
> [Info] [DepthPa
>
> cketStreamParser] 2 packets were lost
>
> [Debug] [DepthPacketStreamParser]
> skipping depth packet
>
> [Info] [DepthPacketStreamParser] 1
> packets were lost
>
> [Debug] [DepthPacketStreamParser]
> skipping depth packet
>
> [Debug] [DepthPacketStreamParser]
> skipping depth packet
>
> [Debug] [DepthPacketStreamParser]
> skipping depth packet
>
> [Debug] [DepthPacketStreamParser]
> skipping depth packet
>
> ^C[Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl]
> stopping...
>
> [Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] canceling
> rgb transfers...
>
> [Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] canceling
> depth transfers...
>
> [Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] stopped
>
> [Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl]
> closing...
>
> [Info] [Freene
>
> ct2DeviceImpl] releasing usb
> interfaces...
>
> [Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl]
> deallocating usb transfer pools...
>
> [Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] closing
> usb device...
>
> [Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] closed
>
> [Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl]
> closing...
>
> [Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] already
> closed, doing nothing

From here, it shows there's some problem with the libva, however, I don't understand what the reminders mean. I used to be happy with the image and continue to work on the ROS. and the ROS results turn to be fairly disappointing!

I found a kinect ROS driver which is called iai-kinect2:

**https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2**

And it fails when I run

**roslaunch kinect2_bridge kinect2_bridge.launch**

This is the main problem.(I want to show you the overall message from the screen, but sorry, I don't know how.) And it shows me no message and always shows some problems:

[Info] [OpenCLDepthPacketProcessorImpl] building OpenCL program...

[Error] [OpenCLDepthPacketProcessorImpl] program = cl::Program(context, source, &err): -34

[ WARN] [1489113544.030635869]: [Kinect2Bridge::initCalibration] using sensor defaults for color intrinsic parameters.

[ WARN] [1489113544.030691456]: [Kinect2Bridge::initCalibration] using sensor defaults for ir intrinsic parameters.

[ WARN] [1489113544.030714924]: [Kinect2Bridge::initCalibration] using defaults for rotation and translation.

[ WARN] [1489113544.030751568]: [Kinect2Bridge::initCalibration] using defaults for depth shift.

[ INFO] [1489113544.122475564]: [DepthRegistration::New] Using OpenCL registration method!

[ INFO] [1489113544.122519103]: [DepthRegistration::New] Using OpenCL registration method!

[ERROR] [1489113544.134612055]: [DepthRegistrationOpenCL::init] depth_registration_opencl.cpp cl::Platform::get(&platforms) failed: -1001

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256644/kinect-2-not-working-with-ros/) by [vcdanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/29640/vcdanda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-03-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vcdanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/29640/vcdanda/) on 2017-03-10**:
The system tells me there's something wrong with the opencl. I will tell you the progress later. Anyone who has met the same problem are welcome to share their experience.

**Comment by [wangshuailpp](https://answers.ros.org/users/30856/wangshuailpp/) on 2017-06-21**:
Hi, Did you solve your problem ? I have the same problem,Can you help me ? Thank you very much!

**Comment by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) on 2018-10-30**:
I have a similar problem though I am running this package [kinect2_tracker](https://github.com/mcgi5sr2/kinect2_tracker), and on launching
roslaunch kinect2_tracker tracker.launch
I get,

```
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.4
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If it is really a opencl problem the why don't you try to run it without opencl at first?
maybe this works:
roslaunch kinect2_bridge kinect2_bridge.launch depth_method:=cpu

---

Originally posted by [Kami](https://answers.ros.org/users/30080/kami/) with karma: 16 on 2017-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0